# How to load a specific build.gradle/gradle.properties for default build process

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have three build.gradle with different name under the same directory

- dev.build.gradle
- uat.build.gradle
- prd.build.gradle

I have 4 issues

1. "gradle build" will just use build.gradle only to start the java plugin build task, but "gradle -b dev.build.gradle" will not start the java plugin build task
2. gradle --help seems not having an option to load a specific gradle.properties. There is another way that creating three directories(dev, uat, prd) under the project root and putting a responding build.gradle version in it. finally, start the java plugin build process. I dont like this because I just want build.gradle or gradle.properties files in the same directory
3. how to copy files in gradle without explicitly specify task name in the command line(gradle build copy).

Comment: ad 1. What do you mean by "default java build process"? ad 2/3 I don't understand the questions. ad 4. Should be turned into a separate question.

Comment: 1. when you type "gradle build" it will run a set of java plugin tasks (comileJava...) 2. when I type "gradle --help", it does not have an option to load the specific gradle.properties file. I can only use -P to define the properties. 3. I mean creating a folder called DEV in the root directory and put the dev version of build.gradle inside of it and then run gradle build under DEV directory.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1. The correct command is `gradle -b dev.build.gradle build`.
ad 2. If you want to use properties files other than build.gradle, you'll have to do it on your own (e.g. using the `java.util.Properties` class). There is also a third-party [properties plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin).
ad 3. This doesn't seem to be a question.
ad 4. You should turn this into a separate question.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `dev.build.gradle`. The `build` task is only available if certain plugins are applied (e.g. `java`). Also note that `-b` only works for single-project builds.